# Allowing websockets over https for local server

Tags: ssl, websocket, https, node-red

I need some direction for projects i made.
I have an existing node-red in local server that send data using websocket to my domain in my hosting. Everything is working fine over http but the problem occured when i used https for my domain. I used websocket ws: before then i changed it wss: to work over https but it still did not work because i realize i need SSL certificate for my local server too. Then, I used self-signed certificate for my local server. It works but i have to manually input my local server DDNS in my browser to allow wss first then back to my hosting domain, i can't expect the users to do this.

I used DDNS on my local server because i have no static IP. I try to call for my ISP for provide static IP but it can't be done in the near future.
Because i have no static IP i can't register domain and i can't use CA Certificate for local server SSL.

My question is:

1. Is there a way to allow ws to work over https?
2. If not, is there a way to allow unsafe wss on my domain page over a button or a prompt when user go to my page? so user don't have to manually input my local server DDNS.
3. Or other way you may suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, Websocket connections are bootstrapped over HTTP, Secure Websocket connections over HTTPS. The TLS session is setup by the HTTPS connection.
2. It's not clear what you are asking here. But the only way to get a self signed certificate to work with a websocket connection is to install that certificate into the browsers trusted certificate store before trying to access the site. The browser will not prompt to trust a certificate for a websocket connection.
3. You can use Letsencrypt with a proper Dynamic DNS setup. This is where you have a fixed domain name and a script on your machine that updates the IP address the domain name points at. The hostname will stay the same so the certificate issued will always have the correct CN/SAN entry. Letsencrypt certificates are signed by a trusted CA certificate that will already be present in your browser.